# USB Host to read directory

Tags: usb

i am working on a project that requires me to read the filenames from a usb flash drive/pen drive. I could use a raspberry pi and be done with but the power requirements for a portable system is limiting. a friend recommend that i look into usb host and a microcontroller to go thru and read directory listing. i can't seem to find the best way of doing this.

Project requirements:

1. Portable
2. Power using a coin cell battery.
3. 1 usb port
4. 3.5in lcd display
5. Read file and folder names.

What is the best way and/or are there tutorials?

Any help is greatly appreciated and pardon my grammar.

Comment: "usb flash drive/pen drive" "Power using a coin cell battery" Nope.

Comment: Your requirements are simply unrealistic. No LCD, USB controller or pen drive alone will work from a coin cell battery. Just use a Rapberry pi and be done with it.

Comment: For the USB part, have a look at the CH375 chips and support boards ("u-disk"). They allow high-level access to FAT USB mass storage devices via SPI. This can be used with any controller and, for a few bucks, does all the USB plus filesystem stuff for you.

Comment: Sorry, the part with FAT support is the CH37**6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide at least 100 to 200 milliamperes at 5 volts to the USB flash for it to work. There's no way you could ever accomplish that from a coin cell battery.

That said, if you can find the way to get enough power, there's several microcontrollers that can do the job. You might grab a hold of Jan Axelson's book "USB Mass Storage" to get an idea how it's basically done.